# Is there any way to save files created by Active Storege with custom file names in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to create a form where users can upload videos by using active storage. But, when files are stored into Storage folder, by default they are using an ID as the file name. Is there any way, I can create files with a custom name like user's email as a file name. So, I can easily distinguish which files are uploaded by whom?

Comment: You are not using active storage correctly. how the file is stored is of no consequence to you. anything saved to active storage is ALREADY attached to whatever it is for. you can set metadata manually through ActiveStorage::Blob

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be concerned about the file name but do try this bit of code that should set the file name upon uploading your files:

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :set_filename

  def set_filename
    if self.active_storage_object.attached?
      self.active_storage_object.blob.update(filename: "desired_filename.#{self.active_storage_object.filename.extension}")
    end
  end
end
```

Source: https://medium.com/fiatinsight/how-to-change-a-filename-in-rails-active-storage-f3e4f26f427e

Read more about the AS storage model:

https://bloggie.io/@kinopyo/7-practical-tips-for-activestorage-on-rails-5-2

Note how the filename field shows up in the active_storage_blobs table.